# Run exe or apk on Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

how to run exe file or apk file on Arduino UNO?

Please suggest me any way to execute both file. Thank you.

Comment: You're really not getting what an Arduino is, are you?

Comment: What is Arduino?

Comment: If a PC or Smartphone is akin to a family car, an Arduino is akin to one of the wheel bolts holding the wheels on.

Comment: @Majenko: but sir, we run c program on arduino. So IDE creates exe and run it on device. How that happened?

Comment: No, the IDE does NOT create an EXE. It creates a HEX. Embedded programs are vastly different to executables that run on an operating system.

Comment: @Majenko ok sir thank you for clearing concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.  An APK is an Android package, and an EXE is a Windows executable.  Neither can run on an Arduino,